# Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined. Is when i use lcrypt in ionic 4

Tags: angular7, ionic4

- When i use lcrypt library in ionic 4, fails. but if comment lines
  10,11 are execute  [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xm6zP.png)

```
const LCrypt = require('lcrypt');
const lcrypt = new LCrypt('KEY');
```

- This is the error, but in my code i dont use the 'slie' property
  [Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tptVT.png)

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
TypeError: Cannot read property 'slice' of undefined
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js (_stream_writable.js:57)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object../node_modules/readable-stream/readable-browser.js (readable-browser.js:4)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object../node_modules/stream-browserify/index.js (index.js:28)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object../node_modules/hash-base/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at Object../node_modules/md5.js/index.js (index.js:3)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:84)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:797)
    at resolvePromise (zone-evergreen.js:754)
    at zone-evergreen.js:858
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:391)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:34182)
    at ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone-evergreen.js:390)
    at Zone.runTask (zone-evergreen.js:168)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone-evergreen.js:559)
```